# PHP MySQL Result displays twice why?

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

I have this simple PHP Script to fetch results from the localhost WAMP server, and when I echo the query it displays one record twice for every record I have!

Result displayed as shown in picture:

[image: PHP MySQL Result displayed twice]

Here is the PHP MySQL script

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
$movie_lists = "";
$no_result = "";

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "localpass";
$dbname = "movieadventuredb";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
//$sql = "SELECT id, movie_quality, movie_release_date FROM movielisting";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM movielisting ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       //echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["movie_name"]. " " .     $row["movie_quality"]. "<br>";

    $id = $row["id"];
    $movie_quality = $row["movie_quality"];
    $release_date = strftime("%Y", strtotime($row["movie_release_date"]));

    $movie_lists .= "<div class='item item-1'><a href='#'><img src='inventory_images/$id.jpg'/></a>
                        <a href='#'><div class='overlay'>
                            <p class='movie_quality $movie_quality'>$movie_quality</p>
                            <p class='movie_year year'>$release_date</p>
                        </div></a>
                    </div>";


     }
   } else {
      $movie_lists = "";
   }
      $conn->close();
 ?>
```

Below is the code for CSS for the listing.

```
.recent_movies_slider .recent_movie_lists {float:left; width:97%;}
.slider-horizontal {width:90%; margin:25px auto; *background:#eee; height:240px; z-index:1;}
.slider-horizontal .item {height:200px; width:150px; margin:20px 10px 0;}
.slider-horizontal .item img {height:200px; width:150px;}
.slider-vertical {width:364px; margin:25px 0; float:left; background:#eee; height:300px;}
.slider-vertical .item {height:80px; width:324px; margin:10px 0 10px 20px;}
.overlay { position: relative; top:-204px; left:0; *right:0; *bottom:0; width:150px; height:200px; z-index:2; display:block; *background:red; *background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); color:#fff;}
.overlay:hover {background:rgba(48, 160, 186, 0.43) url("../default_images/play-button.png") no-repeat; background-position:50% 50%;}
.movie_quality {
position: absolute;
bottom: 5px;
left: 5px;
text-transform:uppercase;
 }
   .hd {background:#B43104; padding:2px; border-radius:2px;}
   .cam {background:#DBA901; padding:2px; border-radius:2px;}
   .year {background:#086A87; padding:2px; border-radius:2px;}
   .movie_year {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 5px;
      right: 5px;
   }
```

and below is the HTML to echo out the result

```
<div class="recent_movie_lists">
   <div id="slider" class="slider-horizontal">
       <?php echo $movie_lists; ?>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why you use `. operator` in this line `$movie_lists .=`??

Comment: what this `$result->fetch_assoc()` returns? Is it returning unique data?

Comment: Post this lines result here please
`echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["movie_name"]. " " .     $row["movie_quality"]. "<br>";`

Comment: @Saty: The `.=` operator appends text to existing text in the variable, which is the desired behavior here.

Comment: http://puu.sh/iCeIE/37125cdc91.png

Comment: Try clearing $movie_lists at the top of your while statement

Comment: Inside the `while` loop, try just echoing out the data, to see if the query is the problem. Maybe you have duplicated information in your database?

Comment: (Once you have fixed the bug, look at the XSS problems here. If you have an item with a `<` in it, your page will break).

Comment: on echo out I get this http://puu.sh/iCeWV/dd4ad49d43.jpg

Comment: I have removed the operator . and I get the first result twice now http://puu.sh/iCf1U/3bede59fd3.png

Comment: check your db for duplicates.....

Comment: What is the actual value of `$result->num_rows`?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this: `$movie_lists = (all your code);` instead of `$movie_lists .= (all your code)`.

Sorry for all the stuff above, as allready answered in the comments. Why don't you just echo out the `while` loop in your `div`?

```
<div class="recent_movie_lists">
   <div id="slider" class="slider-horizontal">
       <?php
       if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       //echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["movie_name"]. " " .     $row["movie_quality"]. "<br>";

    $id = $row["id"];
    $movie_quality = $row["movie_quality"];
    $release_date = strftime("%Y", strtotime($row["movie_release_date"]));

    echo "<div class='item item-1'><a href='#'><img src='inventory_images/$id.jpg'/></a>
                        <a href='#'><div class='overlay'>
                            <p class='movie_quality $movie_quality'>$movie_quality</p>
                            <p class='movie_year year'>$release_date</p>
                        </div></a>
                    </div>";


     }
   } else {
      echo "";
   }
?>
   </div>
</div>
```

As I'm assuming your keeping the HTML and PHP in the same file.

Comment: $movie_list is already defined as an empty string at the top of the file

Comment: did the result is still the same :(

Comment: Your latest suggestion is now stating that Nazmul should be only printing the last row in this query rather than appending each row to the variable in order to show all records

Comment: Even if I echo out in the HTML structure I get the same results

Comment: thansk everyone, the problem was in the css, I am using a carousel image slider and thats whats causing the problem, I removed the plugin and it shows each record once, but trying to find an alternative slider anyway thanks everyone